# Discord bot no longer starts up

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Up until recently my Discord bot has been working perfectly fine, I haven't made any changes to the code and it is in the same same state it was when it was working. For some reason though, now when I try to start my bot through the console with (in my case):

`node my-discord-bot.js`

It simply does nothing, no errors, just blank, I should be receiving a confirmation saying 'Ready!' and my bot should come online, but none of that happens.

Here's the code I've been using to start my bot (which has been working up until recently):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'My Token'

client.once('ready', () => {
console.log('Ready!');
});
```

My console log (no confirmations or errors):
[image]

I genuinely don't know what the problem could be. Please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'My Token';

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to [indent the function code](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse154/18au/resources/styleguide/js/spacing-indentation-js.html#:%7E:text=Spacing%20and%20indentation%20should%20be,than%20the%20previous%20line%27s%20indentation.) as another user told you. Here's another example

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log("Hello World!")
}

myFunction();
```

> Hello World!

However, if we do it without an indent (tab or 4 spaces) like this:

```
function myFunction() {
console.log("Hello World!")
}

myFunction();
```

> Will not work without indent.

Hope this helped, Happy Coding!